# How do you get past the dragon?

Tags: psp, lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

How do you beat the dragon in *LEGO Harry Potter Years 5-7* for the PSP? I've tried so many times, but I always end up dying! I can't find how to do it on any websites.

Comment: Which level is this?  What part specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: It's the part where they are in Gringotts Bank. I can't set the dragon free and get away!

Answer (score 1):

If the PSP version is similar to the other versions, you need to build a bull that contains a bell in order to scare the dragon and remove some of the flames.  You can then walk by the flames, which triggers a cutscene, after which you are moved into the Lestrange vault.

If you watch from the 1:05 to the 2:20 mark of [this YouTube walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBo-9XZEhJI&feature=sh_e_se&list=SL), you'll see how to accomplish it.